# Highcharts axis labels cluttered but after a refresh, it'll be OK

Tags: javascript, highcharts, farsi

I'm using Highcharts to create a negative-stack according to its [document](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack). My language is Persian (Farsi) so I'm using RTL direction overall the project. My problem doesn't limit to negative-stack type, but all charts with xAxis & yAxis.When I open the index.html file at first I'll face with axis labels overlap the chart as you see in the attached image-1, but after a refresh, it will be aligned properly according to the attached image-2.

---

Attachments:

- [image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h71ez.png)
- [image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq7EJ.png)

---

[Sample CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-fast-z42rt?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's caused by the fontFamily. 
After changing that property, everything works as expected.

```js
chart: {
    style: {
      fontFamily: "iranyekan"
    }
  },
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-sun-me5m8

Comment: Do you want to say that this problem caused by the **iranyekan** font?

Comment: When I changed that font, it works properly. That is why I suspect that this issue is caused by this font.